# Laravel 9 Breeze Install: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-breeze

I want to install Laravel Breeze in my project but I got an error like this

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^1.20 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.20.0, 1.x-dev].
    - laravel/breeze[v1.20.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^10.0 -> found illuminate/console[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/breeze:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/breeze:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Anyone know how to fix it? And what I want to do is installing Laravel Breeze in Laravel 9. Thank You

Comment: `laravel/breeze` with the version requirement `^1.20`  requires Laravel v10. If you want to use any older version of Laravel, you need to use a different version requirement, like `^1.11` (which is one the first versions compatible with Laravel 9)